# Converting RGB to HEX fails

Tags: javascript, hex, rgb

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb) question and many others, I'm trying to convert an rgb value to a hex value.

Copying/pasting the most used and accepted answer, I've made this script

```
function componentToHex(c) {
            var hex = c.toString(16);
            return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
        }

function rgbToHex(rgb) {

            var colors = rgb.split("(")
            colors = colors[1].split(")")
            colors = colors[0].split(",")

            var r = 255 - parseInt(colors[0])
            var g = 255 - parseInt(colors[1])
            var b = 255 - parseInt(colors[2])

            return componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
        }

alert(rgbToHex("rgb(0, 51, 255)"))
```

Result:

```
ffcc00
```

Expected result:

```
0033ff
```

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `parseInt` result directly, not `255` minus the value:

```
var r = parseInt(colors[0])
var g = parseInt(colors[1])
var b = parseInt(colors[2])
```

You're currently producing the *exact opposite* color by outputting values *complementary* to (rather than *equivalent* to) the input values.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `255 - parseInt(colors[i])`, it should be `parseInt(colors[i])`.

In your current implementation - if red is 0, 255 - 0 = 255, which in hex is FF.